# Avoiding Circular Dependency in C header files

Tags: c, header, circular-dependency

```
 header1.h   
        -----------------
        struct A{
        int a;
        B *b;
        };

    header2.h  
    -------------------
    #include"header1.h"

    typedef struct b{
    int aa;
    char bb;
    int cc;
    }B;

    main.c  
    --------------------
    #include<header2.h>

    main(){

    struct A *ace;
    ace = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
    ace->b = malloc(sizeof(B));
    }
```

The problem: Basically, header1.h needs to use a struct defined in header2.h.

The Dilemma: Since header2.h includes header1.h, If i include header2.h in header1.h I will be introducing a circular dependency.

Some solutions: One way to solve the problem would be use a void pointer, but is there any other way? I tried forward declaring it, but it says "redifining a typedef".

Comment: Add [include guards](https://www.google.com/search?q=include+guards&oq=include+guards&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.226j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) to your headers.

Comment: This wont solve your question but is supposed to be a style hint: be consistent on the include statements - dont use `< >` on non system provided headers but only `" "` - always.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily prevent your header files from being included multiple times by wrapping them like this

```
#ifndef FOO_H_ /* include guard */
#define FOO_H_

/* * * * * insert foo.h here * * * * */

#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

Comment: Do not use leading underscore(s) followed by capital letters as they are reserved on many systems/setups.

Answer (score 4):

So the problem you have is the pointer

```
B *b;
```

in struct A. Since this is a pointer an incomplete type is ok as long as you tell it that's what this is.

```
typedef struct a {
    int a;
    struct B *b;
} A;
```

or you could use the prototype form:

```
struct B;
typedef struct a {
    int a;
    B *b;
};
```

The compiler just wants to know *what type of thing* the pointer points-to just here, it doesn't actually care what it looks like in more detail until you first start trying to dereference it.

Comment: So its basically functioning as a void pointer. But is it resolving itself later? Or whenever i use it i have to cast it ?

Comment: `struct B` is basically a prototype for the full declaration of B, it tells the compiler the minimum it needs to know to be able to create a pointer to a struct B. Creating a pointer doesn't need to know what the inside of the class looks like, just what it's called and that it is a structure (as opposed to a union or a typedef).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use forward declaration in this case as struct B appears only as a pointer and dont try to access 
any members of struct B. The compiler would be happy and I assume only the source code would access the members.

header1.h:

```
struct B;

struct A{
    int a;
    B *b;   
}
```